# Networkx - outdegree calculation

Tags: networkx, digraphs

I'm calculating the outdegree over a series of different graphs. However, the last 'levels' in the graphs always produce a 0 outdegree when they shouldn't. For example, in the picture below the uppermost level nodes (labeled as 4) all have an outdegree of 0 (when it should be 1):

```
[Graph]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAi1H.jpg
```

Everything else calculates correctly. Any tips? I've created this graph from a previous piece of code (not mine), and can provide the piece where I'm creating the networkx graph. I could be adding edges incorrectly, but from the docs I seem to be fine. The 'graph' is the networkx DiGraph() which is passed into the function:

```
[Code - 1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4gGL.png
[Code - 2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7reI.png
[Output]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRQK3.png
```

From the output the only one that should have a zero outdegree is the first, Part9518. You can see the visual of this graph in the first link.

Sorry about the links -- not enough rep to upload in post.

Comment: Something hasn't gone right with your links.

Comment: It will also help if you provide the code you've run and tell us what the output is.

Comment: The links work for me -- copy and paste, or are they actually suppose to be 'links'? I'll upload what I've run. I'll upload output example too.

Comment: Okay - link seems to be working for me now.  But please, put the code directly into your question as text, not an image.  (indenting 4 places makes text be treated as a block of code).  You'll get much better answers if the answerer can copy and paste your code to run it.

Comment: and reduce this to a [mcve] (are all of the nodes needed, or do you get the same problem with just 5 or so nodes?).  Usually I find that the process of creating the MCVE results in me figuring out what the mistake is.  So it's a good practice to get into.

Comment: similarly when you create the MCVE, you should be able to put the output in as text.  Basically, nothing that is text should be uploaded as an image.  It's too hard to work with.

Comment: Please consider adding your code directly into the question.